# How to assign key to object Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to create array like this:

```
vm.finished_tasks = [];
```

inside foreach:

```
(value.finished === 1) ? vm.finished_tasks[item.id].push(value) : '';
```

There are 2 foreach loop `item` is from main loop, `value` is from loop inside...

I want to be able to access from tamlate something like this:

```
{{ vm.finished_tasks[1] }}
```

Comment: `vm.finished_tasks.push(value)`

Comment: {{ vm.finished_tasks[1] | json }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
vm.finished_tasks[item.id].push(value)
```

means value of `item.id` index is an array  and push that value into that array

But you never declared `vm.finished_tasks[item.id]` as array instead you declared only `vm.finished_tasks` as an array

If you wanna just print index of `vm.finished_tasks`

The try like this

```
vm.finished_tasks.push(value)
```

But you wanna push data in `item.id` index

Then try like this

```
if(!vm.finished_tasks[item.id])
  vm.finished_tasks[item.id]=[];

(value.finished === 1) ? vm.finished_tasks[item.id].push(value) : '';
```